# Call rails app from another app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, web-applications, rack

I have an application that has some model and services. I need those entities from another app from another directory. How can I share them? I don't want to use public API or REST interface via the internet, but just call services in local. Can I configure it with Rack?

Comment: did you try mounting it as a rails engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share the code then the rails way is to make they as `gems` and use them in your applications.

If you are using rails > 3 , best way is to  do it via [rails engines](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html), Its easy to learn and more elegant.

But simplest and **not recommended** way is to have your methods as ruby modules/classes and use then in your each project (by having them in you lib directory or some were)

HTH